# How to Check if an array is already sorted in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a small task in php. I have a simple array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 50
    [1] => 100
    [2] => 150

)
```

Is there a php built in function which i can use so that it can return true or false, accordingly if array is already sorted or not, Or any other php script for this, no loops. I know it is easy with loops and conditions.

Comment: When you know, it's easy, why do you ask?

Comment: What if there is an array with these values array(150,30,0)

Comment: @KingCrunch what's wrong with asking if there is a built-in function to do something simple? I often wonder that myself when writing small utility functions.

Comment: You could use [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/class.arrayaccess.php) to write a class, which stores a *sorted*-flag. This flag could then be queried.

Comment: @Andrew - there's nothing wrong with asking, but it's difficult to have in-built function for determining whether an array is sorted. Reason being is that you have multiple sorting algorithms and a computer can't know whether something *is* sorted unless it tries to sort it and reach the same output as input, making the question kinda - well, silly.

Comment: OK. Well i appereciate help of all people given. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @raheelshan There is nothing wrong with asking, but usually if someone asks for a _builtin_ function, it sounds like he never touched the manual ... Thats disappointing. :X

Comment: i tried after searching and found nothing therefore i asked that i might be missing something

Comment: Great question, upvoted, thanks!  It's been a decade or so, maybe a different answer should selected as the correct one?  Just speaking for the community, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you can try with this code:

```
<?php

$sort = array(
    0 => 50,
    1 => 100,
    2 => 150
);

$default = $sort;
sort($sort);

$flag = true;
foreach($sort as $key=>$value)
    if($value!=$default[$key])
        $flag = false;  

if($flag)
    echo "Already sorted";  
else
    echo "Not Already sorted";  
?>
```

Comment: That looks suspiciously like a loop. :)

Answer (score 11):

You can compare your input array with sorted one if they are equal.

```
$input  = array(50, 100, 150);
$sorted = array_values($input);
sort($sorted);

if ( $input === $sorted ) {
  // input array was already sorted
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function arraySorted($array) {
    $a = $array;
    $b = $array;
    sort($b);
    if ($a == $b){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//test for [0],[3],[2]
$input  = array(0 => 250,
                3 => 100,
                2 => 150);
var_dump($input);
echo "<br />";
//array(3) { [0]=> int(250) [3]=> int(100) [2]=> int(150) }

var_dump(arraySorted($input));
echo "<br />";
//bool(false) 

//test for [0],[1],[2]
$input  = array(0 => 250,
                1 => 100,
                2 => 150);
var_dump($input);
echo "<br />";
//array(3) { [0]=> int(250) [1]=> int(100) [2]=> int(150) }

var_dump(arraySorted($input));
echo "<br />";
//bool(false)

//test for [0],[3],[2] and asc values
$input  = array(0 => 50,
                1 => 100,
                2 => 150);
var_dump($input);
echo "<br />";
//array(3) { [0]=> int(50) [1]=> int(100) [2]=> int(150) }

var_dump(arraySorted($input));
echo "<br />";
//bool(true)
```

Comment: Taking out my -1, but i do not like it, i understand sorted array where values are sorted, keys are not important. For these, your code does not work. But in original question, this is clearly defined, so OK. Just to know that in my eyes, this array: array('one' => 50, 'two' => 100, 'three' => 150); is sorted, but your code will return false

Answer (score 2):

You could use `array_reduce` to compare each element to the next, and throw an exception if the array is unsorted.

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP doesn't hold the state if an array is sorted or not it can't know. And the only other solution is to iterate over the array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite surprised no one proposed to actually check input array itself.
Maybe it's my C++ background, but I just can't not to care about algorithm's complexity and frankly speaking, copying and sorting array is just silly.

```
namespace Util\Functions;

function compare($lhs, $rhs, $descendingOrder = false)
{
    $result = 0;
    if ($lhs < $rhs) {
        $result = -1;
    } else if ($lhs > $rhs) {
        $result = 1;
    }

    if ($descendingOrder) {
        $result *= -1;
    }

    return $result;
}

function isSorted(array $arr, callable $compareFunction = null)
{
    $count = count($arr);
    if ($count < 2){ 
        return true;
    }
    if ($compareFunction === null) {
        $compareFunction = 'Util\Functions\compare';     
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if ($compareFunction($arr[$i - 1], $arr[$i]) > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

P.S. I know OP asked no loops but since there is no good solution, I decided to post code that anyone could just copy-paste to his project.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare it with already sorted array, or you can control it via SQL query using `order by` if the array is coming from database, rest no inbuilt function in php to check this.

Answer (score 0):

This will work regardless on keys:

```
$a = array(5 => 'aple', 3 => 'banana', 1 =>'citron');
$b = array(2 => 'orange', 1 => 'wine', 5 => 'apple');

echo arraySorted($a) ? "sorted" : 'not';
echo "\n";
echo arraySorted($b) ? "sorted" : 'not';

function arraySorted($array) {
   $sorted = $vals = array_values($array);
   sort($sorted);
       return $sorted === $vals;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can't know weather they are sorted, because there are so many orderings. Just for numbers there can be ascending, descending, absolute ascending, absolute... You get the picture. **However algorithm that check if array is sorted is independent of sort order**.

What follow is `isSorted` function, that if given `comparator` will check if elements of array are sorted in that order. That way `isSorted` do not know what order is being tested, but instead delegate that to `comparator`.

Since question show numbers in specific order, I also provided `comparator` for ascending order based on php `<`.

```
$xs = [
  50,
  100,
  150
];

// Here is example of comparator, it have to take 2 elements, and return boolean signaling weather relationship you want to test holds true
$comparator = function($current, $next) {
  return $current < $next;
};

function isSorted($xs, $comparator){

  $answer = true;
  foreach ($xs as $key => $current) {
    if(!isset($xs[$key + 1]))
        continue;

    $next = $xs[$key + 1];

    $answer = $answer && $comparator($current, $next);
  }

  return $answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see lots of answers that are performing a full array sort then comparing the whole original versus the whole sorted copy.  This of course is not as efficient as it could be.  To check if the array is sorted, you don't need to copy it or mutate it or sort it -- just iterate it and compare as you go.  A script with an early `break`/`return` will do the absolute minimum work.

(I also see a couple of answers calling `array_values()`, but I can't understand why re-indexing is valuable.)

For instance: ([Demo of a true and a false outcome](https://3v4l.org/Rlgob))

```
$array = [50, 50, 100, 175];  // no break

$last = reset($array);
$isSorted = true;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($last > $value) {
        $isSorted = false;
        break;
    }
    $last = $value;
}
var_export($isSorted);  //true
```

This will only ever make a complete run of your data if the array is completely sorted or if the final element is unsorted.

But really, if you are concerned with whether or not the array is sorted, you can probably just sort it and move on with your scripting.

If you need something that will perform an ultra fast evaluation because you are dealing with an insanely huge amount of data, then you probably want to employ a language outside of php.